# Guess a number between 1 and 100 (revision 1)

Tags: c#, beginner, number-guessing-game

I have taken the critiques from the [original post](/questions/158247/guess-a-number-between-1-and-100) and tried to refactor. I used int.TryParse and that cleaned up quite nicely. What can I further improve on?

Edit: ([Guess a number between 1 and 100 (revision 2)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158571/guess-a-number-between-1-and-100-revision-2))

```
//Program.cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //RunTheGame game = new RunTheGame();
        GuessingGame game = new GuessingGame();

        do
        {
            game.Play();
        } while (game.PlayAgain());

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for playing\nPress any key to close the program.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class GuessingGame
{
    int _lbound = 1;
    int _ubound = 100;
    bool _isHumanGuessing;
    Random _rnd = new Random();


    public void Play()
    {
        int guessCount = 0;
        int _number = _rnd.Next(_lbound, _ubound);

        Console.Clear();
        WriteBeginMessage();

        _isHumanGuessing = IsHumanGuessing();

        guessCount = DoTheGuessing(_number,_lbound,_ubound);

        Console.WriteLine($"It took {guessCount} tries to get it right.");
        Console.WriteLine($"The correct number was {_number}.");
    }

    private void WriteBeginMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the numberline game.");
        Console.WriteLine("Try and guess the number in the fewest guesses possible.");
        Console.WriteLine($"The boundaries {_lbound} and {_ubound} are included in the range.");
        Console.WriteLine("Lets begin");
    }

    private bool IsHumanGuessing()
    {
        int player=0;
        string resp;

        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Choose who guesses:");
            Console.WriteLine("1) You");
            Console.WriteLine("2) The computer");
            resp = Console.ReadLine();

            if (player == 1 || player == 2)
            {
                if (player == 1)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    public bool PlayAgain()
    {
        string resp;
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again?");

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("(y / n):");
            resp = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        }
        while (!(resp == "Y" || resp == "N"));

        if (resp == "Y")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private int GetHumanInput()
    {
        int guess = 0;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Guess a number between {_lbound} and {_ubound}");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess: ");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out guess);
        } while (guess == 0);
        return guess;
    }

    private int GetComputerInput(int lBound, int uBound)
    {
        return (lBound + uBound) / 2;
    }

    private void DisplayDifference(int guess, int signValue)
    {
        string pf;    //Can one of the 2 switches be eliminated?
        switch (signValue)
        {
            case 1:
                pf = "Too high";
                break;
            case -1:
                pf = "Too low";
                break;
            default:
                pf = "You guessed it";
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{guess}: {pf}");
    }

    private int DoTheGuessing(int number, int lbound, int ubound)   
    {
        int signValue;
        int guess;
        int _guessCount=0;
        do
        {
            _guessCount++;

            if (_isHumanGuessing)
                guess = GetHumanInput();
            else
            {
                guess = GetComputerInput(lbound, ubound);
            }

            signValue = Math.Sign(guess - number);

            if (!_isHumanGuessing)
            {
                switch (signValue)
                {
                    case 1:
                        ubound = guess;
                        break;
                    case -1:
                        lbound = guess;
                        break;
                }
            }

            DisplayDifference(guess, signValue);

        } while (signValue != 0);

        return _guessCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you have just posted an edit in the original thread rather than create a new one?

Comment: @NathanHoy that would have been rolled back within a minute, as all answer-invalidating edits are (or should be) across the entire Stack Exchange network. See [help/someone-answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for all the details.

Comment: @Mat'sMug My apologies, will bare in mind for next time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WriteBeginMessage**
Does this stay on the screen long enough to be read?
The first thing `IsHumanGuessing` does is clear the screen which removes the begin message.

**IsHumanGuessing**
It looks as if this doesn't run correctly.
At the top, we set `player` to 0, we then read the `resp` into a string and check the value of `player`. At no point do we set `player` with a value from `resp`.

```
if(player == 1)
  return true;
else
 return false;
```

can be simplified to

```
return player == 1;
```

**PlayAgain**
Why two different loop styles? `IsHumanGuessing` uses an infinite loop and returns from inside the loop.  `PlayAgain` loops until we have valid input and then returns. A single style makes things easier to follow and reduces the possibility of error.