# Guess a number between 1 and 100 (revision 2)

Tags: c#, beginner

Further revision based on comments ([Guess a number between 1 and 100 (revision 1)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158452/guess-a-number-between-1-and-100-revision-1)). Is there any issue with using `DisplayBeginMessage` in the ctor (¿constructor?) of `GuessingGame`? Is there any preference over the ternary

```
guess = _isHumanGuessing ? GetHumanInput() : GetComputerInput(lbound, ubound);
```

or this form

```
if (_isHumanGuessing)
    guess = GetHumanInput();
else
    guess = GetComputerInput(lbound, ubound);
```

or, finally, this form?

```
if (_isHumanGuessing)
{
    guess = GetHumanInput();
{
else
{
    guess = GetComputerInput(lbound, ubound);
}
```

Or does it come down to using `{...}` when multiple instructions are part of the condition, or is it preference? I can see the ternary operator makes it very succinct an clear, once you know what the operator does. I'm trying to educate myself as to best practices.

```
//Program.cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //RunTheGame game = new RunTheGame();
        GuessingGame game = new GuessingGame();

        do
        {
            game.Play();
        } while (game.PlayAgain());

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for playing\nPress any key to close the program.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

//Game.cs
class GuessingGame
{
    int _lbound = 1;
    int _ubound = 100;
    bool _isHumanGuessing;
    Random _rnd = new Random();

    public GuessingGame()
    {
        DisplayBeginMessage();
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        int guessCount = 0;
        int _number = _rnd.Next(_lbound, _ubound);

        Console.Clear();

        _isHumanGuessing = IsHumanGuessing();

        guessCount = DoTheGuessing(_number, _lbound, _ubound);

        Console.WriteLine($"It took {guessCount} tries to get it right.");
        Console.WriteLine($"The correct number was {_number}.");
    }

    private void DisplayBeginMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the numberline game.");
        Console.WriteLine("Try and guess the number in the fewest guesses possible.");
        Console.WriteLine($"The boundaries {_lbound} and {_ubound} are included in the range.");
        Console.WriteLine("Lets begin: Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private bool IsHumanGuessing()
    {
        int player = 0;
        string resp;

        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Choose who guesses:");
            Console.WriteLine("1) You");
            Console.WriteLine("2) The computer");

            resp = Console.ReadLine();

            int.TryParse(resp, out player);

            if (player == 1 || player == 2)
                return player == 1;

        } while (true);
    }

    public bool PlayAgain()
    {
        string resp;
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again?");

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("(y / n):");
            resp = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        }
        while (!(resp == "Y" || resp == "N"));

        return resp == "Y";
    }

    private int GetHumanInput()
    {
        int guess = 0;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Guess a number between {_lbound} and {_ubound}");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess: ");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out guess);
        } while (guess == 0);
        return guess;
    }

    private int GetComputerInput(int lBound, int uBound)
    {
        return (lBound + uBound) / 2;
    }

    private void DisplayDifference(int guess, int signValue)
    {
        string pf;    //Can one of the 2 switches be eliminated?
        switch (signValue)
        {
            case 1:
                pf = "Too high";
                break;
            case -1:
                pf = "Too low";
                break;
            default:
                pf = "You guessed it";
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{guess}: {pf}");
    }

    private int DoTheGuessing(int number, int lbound, int ubound)
    {
        int signValue;
        int guess;
        int _guessCount = 0;
        do
        {
            _guessCount++;

            guess = _isHumanGuessing ? GetHumanInput() : GetComputerInput(lbound, ubound);

            signValue = Math.Sign(guess - number);

            if (!_isHumanGuessing)
            {
                switch (signValue)
                {
                    case 1:
                        ubound = guess;
                        break;
                    case -1:
                        lbound = guess;
                        break;
                }
            }

            DisplayDifference(guess, signValue);

        } while (signValue != 0);

        return _guessCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: You must use braces when you use multiple instructions.  You should always use braces to help prevent bugs. Use my analyzer and code fix in VS 2017 to fix the ones without braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Constructor Use**
From [Framework Design Guidelines - Constructor Design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229060(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Constructors should not do much work other than capture the constructor parameters. The cost of any other processing should be delayed until required.

We only want to show the message the first time the game is played so we can have a flag to keep track of whether it has been called, or make method public and let the driver invoke it.

As a person who does an amount of work in a language with no ternary operator, I say use it as much as appropriate (though nesting it 3 or 4 levels deep can be very hard to follow). I *would* push for formatting it differently

```
guess = _isHumanGuessing 
            ? GetHumanInput() 
            : GetComputerInput(lbound, ubound);
```

because I find it easier to quickly see what is happening but we are getting into coding convention wars here and this point is heavily A Matter Of Personal Preference [AMOPP (tm)]

As @Hosch250 says above **always** put in the braces in `if/else` blocks. I have seen a *LOT* of errors along the lines of

```
if (something)
   DoThis();
   DoThat();
```

where the intent is only to `DoThat()` if something is true.

The only place I don't use the braces (see AMOPP (tm) above) is simple control statements and they are deliberately formatted to indicate that they are the only statement invoked.

```
if(something) then break;

// or

if(_value == value) then return
```

**Game Design**
The game is hardcoded to be between 1 and 100. This could easily be parameterised in the constructor.

```
public class GuessingGame
{
    private readonly int _initialLowerBound;
    private readonly int _initialUpperBound;


    public GuessingGame(int initialLowerBound = 1, int initialUpperBound = 100)
    {
        _initialLowerBound = initialLowerBound; 
        _initialUpperBound = initialUpperBound;
    }
```

At the moment, we have different signatures for `GetHumanInput()` and `GetComputerInput()`.  This is because we don't need the adjusted upper/lower bounds for the human, we always tell them to guess between 1 and 100

We could change things so that even though we don't use the values they are still passed into  `GetHumanInput()`. Why?

Well this means that both methods now have a signature of the shape of

```
int fname(int lbound, int ubound)
```

which means they can both be represented by a [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of the type

```
Func<int, int, int>
```

We can now change `IsHumanGuessing()` to

```
private Func<int, int, int> GetPlayer()
{

     do
     {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Choose who guesses:");
        Console.WriteLine("1) You");
        Console.WriteLine("2) The computer");

        string resp = Console.ReadLine();
        int player;
        int.TryParse(resp, out player);

        if (player == 1)
           return GetHumanInput;

        if (player == 2)
           return GetComputerInput;

     } while (true);
  }
```

This means that we can remove all the branches in the code relating to `_isHumanGuessing`

```
public void Play()
{
    var number = _rnd.Next(_initialLowerBound, _initialUpperBound);

    Console.Clear();

    var guessCount = DoTheGuessing(number,
                                   _initialLowerBound,
                                   _initialUpperBound,
                                   GetPlayer());

    Console.WriteLine($"It took {guessCount} tries to get it right.");
    Console.WriteLine($"The correct number was {number}.");
}

private int DoTheGuessing(int number, int lbound, int ubound, Func<int, int, int> guessDelegate)
{
     int signValue;
     int guessCount = 0;
     do
     {
        guessCount++;

        int guess = guessDelegate(lbound, ubound);

        signValue = Math.Sign(guess - number);

        switch (signValue)
        {
           case 1:
              ubound = guess;
              break;
           case -1:
              lbound = guess;
              break;
        }

        DisplayDifference(guess, signValue);

     } while (signValue != 0);

     return guessCount;
  }
```

We could also (at a very future date) replace the delegate with an [interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) and provide a list of implementations of the interface to the class allowing us to add different types of guessers without having to change the core of the game.

```
public interface IGuesser
{
    string Name {get;}
    int Guess(int lbound, int ubound);
}
```

Another day's work...

**Edit: Answers to questions**

1. The `readonly` modifier is used on values that are set during construction/initialization and not changed thereafter. It acts as a communication telling those who are reading the code of the intent - these are not intended to be changed.  Generally code should as restrictive as possible.

   - If a method/field is not needed outside the class, make it private.
   - If a variable is not intended to be changed, make it readonly.
2. There is no need to parameterize the boundaries if we are creating a sample game for practicing programming; it smacks of over-engineering and violates [You ain't gonna need it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it), but I stuck it in to demonstrate how adding the parameters change it from a fixed 'Guess between 1 and 100' game to a 'Guess between two numbers' games.
3. A delegate is a way of encapsulating the information which we need to call a method allowing us to pass this information around and invoke the method indirectly. In our code we pass into `DoTheGuessing()` a delegate for the guessing.  We return from `GetPlayer` a delegate which contains the information for invoking either `GetHumanInput` or `GetComputerInput` and when we call the `guessDelegate` we execute whichever of those methods was selected.
4. In `GetPlayer()` we return a delegate that is a Func, a function that takes two ints as parameters and returns an int.  Depending upon the users selection we return a delegate which allows us to invoke either `GetHumanInput` or `GetComputerInput`. This is not [short circuting](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/short-circuit-evaluation-in-c-sharp/), it is returning a delegate to one of these methods depending upon the user's input.
5. The use of `var` is pretty much a matter of personal preference. [Implicit typing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of variables allows one to declare a variable as `var` and let the compiler work out what the type should be. I like and use it. Not everyone does.

Comment: Bounds are accessible via `GuessingGame` fields, you don't not have to pass them as parameters to `DoTheGuessing` method, unless you want to make this method static for some reason. Also I agree that `guessDelegate` should be an interface.

Comment: Yes. It can be shortened down more. I was just trying to get across one point without fully changing the code. The interface, with separate 'Guesser' instances and a provider (and perhaps a dynamic menu) is a better way to go, but the question is tagged as 'beginner'. Delegates I can shoe-horn into a beginner category...mostly

Comment: 1) Why is [`readonly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) used?  Is it because once set, you want those values to be used for the entirety of the program?
2) What benefits are derived from parameterizing the boundaries?
3) I''ve heard of delegates and have tried reading about them but don't fully understand their uses yet. Can you explain further?
4) Based on your change to `IsHumanGuessing` why did you use the from `if (player==#) \n return FunctionName`? Is that for short circuiting?
5) In `Play` type `var` used for `number` & `guesscount`. Why?